# Braintree credit card fields disabled in Latest version of Chrome - Magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have Magento 2.1 enabled with the native checkout, I noticed that the credit card fields stay disabled in the latest version of Chrome, in all other browsers it works fine.

Anyone had the same issue?

See below the answer from Braintree (They are mentioning extension but I'm running the native checkout, not an external extension):

> I’ve run some tests on your website, and I see that the credit card
>   fields are disabled in Chrome(latest version), but working in other
>   browsers. The Braintree extension that you are using has integrated
>   our Hosted Fields for its payment form, which renders an iframe to
>   handle input for each field where your customer enters credit card
>   details. I see that the iframe is not loading in Chrome, that should
>   be the reason why the credit card fields are shown as disabled and
>   cannot accept input.
>
> I also tested my own Hosted Fields integration and it works fine in
>   Chrome. What I believe is happening is that the Braintree extension
>   that you are using is not compatible with your one step checkout
>   extension in Chrome.

**UPDATE**

That's a known issue in Magento 2.1 and the fix will be available in Magento 2.1.1
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5903